# Rails / Ruby - How to check an Users download and upload speed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

How is it possible to check a users upload and download speed in MB/s ?

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Comment: It's not clear what the user is uploading or downloading, which might be important. I think (from the answer below) that you might be asking "How do I check a user's connection speed?".

Comment: You are right to may be misleading. It is the speed that I want to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To time a download you could do something like this in your action:

```
def download
  start_time = Time.now
  file_size = File.size('never_gonna_give_you_up.mp3') / 1024.0 / 1024.0
  send_file("never_gonna_give_you_up.mp3")
  logger.info("Download took #{Time.now - start_time}s at #{file_size / (Time.now - start_time)} MB/s")
 end
```

For timing a user upload you wouldn't be able to check how long it took the user to upload something strictly in Ruby or Rails since the request is not processed until the user is finished uploading. What you could do is have javascript populate a field (e.g. upload_start_time) when the form is submitted and then subtract the time at the beginning of the action like this:

```
def upload
  upload_time = Time.parse(params[:upload_start_time]) - Time.now
  file_size = params[:file].size / 1024.0 / 1024.0 # assuming 'file' is the name of the field
  logger.info("Upload took #{upload_time} at #{file_size / upload_time} MB/s")
end
```

This won't be precise but it should give you a good approximation.

Comment: Yes although I think this might log the time even if the user clicks no--I'm not sure. That also brings up the question of whether that time that the app waits for the user to accept is included in the download time and unfortunately I think it would be. I'm not sure if you could get around this to get a better measurement at the rails level.

Comment: Then it is a problem. There are plenty of internet speedtests online. Just wondering how they are working. I was thinking it was serverside.

Comment: I  have spyed on the html request on a speedtest website and it seems like it is getting 4 random images of 4 different sizes to measure the speed and then the posting them.

Comment: So most of the speed tests you see online are flash. However, you could use the download code above to time a download but send the user something that his/her browser would automatically accept like a css/js file or an image. Alternatively you could do something in javascript where you send the user a page in html with a timestamp on it and then calculate the time difference in javascript.