# How to calculate file download and upload durations in rails production with passenger and nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, carrierwave

I have a Rails 4 app in production running on a single VPS with nginx and passenger.

I use jquery-fileupload + carrierwave to store uploaded images in my own public folder.

I am trying to find a good solution to calculate and save upload and download times and durations, preferably using server-side code.

So far, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460658/rails-ruby-how-to-check-an-users-download-and-upload-speed) answer, which tries to calculate the duration with ruby code.

It basically uses the rails send_file command to send the file and saves the time before and after the send_file command to know the duration. This has two main problems:

1. The send_file command (along with its similar alternatives) pauses the ruby code until file transfer is complete (at least in development), which is not practical.
2. In production with passenger and nginx, this pause does not happen, and the requests are not blocked, probably because the send_file command delegates the actual file transfer to nginx and immediately continues the code. When I time uploads/downloads in this situation, I always get a few milliseconds!

So, I'm stuck.

I was thinking a viable solution would be to somehow extract this information from nginx or passenger logs once a day using a cron job. I'm not sure if it can be done however.

Comment: Nginx has built-in variables that may be helpful to you: **$msec**, **$request_time**, **$upstream_response_time**. A custom HTTP header may keep value of $msec to determine the time when X-Accel-Redirect requests started to happen.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into those.